# async await callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

I am using couchbase ottaman package:

```
let transaction = new Transaction({name:'Couch'});
    transaction.save((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

but can I use async/await with this package?

```
async create(){
        let transaction = new Transaction({name:'Couch'});
        try{
            await transaction.save();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

I am getting error:

```
node_modules\ottoman\lib\modelinstance.js:457
            callback(err);
            ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you have to check if it returns promise - you can use it out of box. If not - you can promisify function you need.
Something like this in result:

```
function saveModel(transaction) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    transaction.save(err => {
      if (err) 
         reject(err);
      else
         resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Such function can be used with async/await:

```
async create(){
  let transaction = new Transaction({name:'Couch'});
    try{
      await saveModel(transaction);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Another option is to view [source files](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ottoman&type=), but I'm too lazy to do it.

Comment: Ottoman does not return promise.

Comment: @Alvin, no-one claims it does. Try this code, which *promisifies* the `transaction.save` method. Just make sure to put an `else` before `resolve()`.